# Character run faster with 2 buttons pressed at same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make controller script for my character. Everything works ok, but when i press 2 movement buttons at same time my character moves faster.

If i press `D` it moves slower than if i press `D+S` or `D+W`. How i can fix that? I want my character to move with same speed.

Code:

```
AnimationsCharacter animations;
CharacterController controller;
Transform camera;

Vector3 camForward;
Vector3 camRight;
Vector3 motion;

float horizontal;
float vertical;
float sprint;
float inputMagnitude;

float speed;
float defaultSpeed = 5;
float sprintSpeed = 10;
void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    animations = GetComponent<AnimationsCharacter>();
    camera = Camera.main.transform;
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetMoveInput();
}

public void GetMoveInput()
{
    horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    sprint = Input.GetAxis("Sprint");

    if (horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0)
    {
        if(sprint != 0)
        {
            speed = sprintSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = defaultSpeed;
        }
        CalculateCamera();
        Move();
    }
}

public void CalculateCamera()
{
    camForward = camera.forward;
    camRight = camera.right;

    camForward.y = 0;
    camRight.y = 0;

    camForward = camForward.normalized;
    camRight = camRight.normalized;
}

public void Move()
{
    motion = (camForward * vertical + camRight * horizontal);
    inputMagnitude = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical).sqrMagnitude;
    controller.Move(motion * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    animations.AnimMovement(inputMagnitude);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(motion);
}
```

I tried different things, like `/2` if 2 buttons pressed. Seems like i do something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`Normalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Normalize.html) the `motion` in the case that it has a `sqrMagnitude > 1` (= `magnitude > 1` but cheaper access) so it has always `magnitude <= 1`.

```
motion = (camForward * vertical + camRight * horizontal);
if(motion.sqrMagnitude > 1)
{
    motion.Normalize();
}
```